# Slate writeback to Phonograph2 fails with Phonograph2:EditPayloadTooLarge

Tags: palantir-foundry

When writing to a Phonograph table sometimes queries exceed the maximum allowed size of 190kB. Is there any way to work around this limit?

The context to that question is that users should define custom filters on a dashboard. Upon storing a filter definition I want to keep track of the data items that are matching the current filter to later being able to identify newly matching data items, e.g. when new data arrives in the system. However, the list of data ids that match the filter is sometimes too big, and hence the error occurs.

Thanks,
Tobias

Answer (score 1):

Can you try forcing the user to use a group of filters.
We had this problem and were told that the intention of allowing a small package size of Phonograph is with the thought process that we base our filters on a set of fields that collectively always result a finite set of rows. For example a given set of geo filters/ set of product dim filters.